# generic optional function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, generics, function-pointers

I would like to build a generic object which can store and call multiple tr1::functions.

So far, I used a typedef and vector to store them in a member fields of objects, like

```
typedef tr1::function<void (SomeObject)> SomeFunction;
```

and

```
vector<SomeFunction> functionStorage
```

this works, but I have to duplicate the code for adding and calling the function in every object. So I tried to come up with a more generic solution. Ideally, I wanted some template object where I can directly pass the function typedef, including both return type and parameter Types like

```
template<typename T>
class FunctionStore
{
    public:
        FunctionStore<T>();
        virtual ~FunctionStore<T>();

        void addFunction( const T &newFunction);
        void callAllFunctions( const Parameter & parameter ) const;
    private:
        vector<T> functionStorage;
};
```

but this didn't work out because I couldn't get the parameter list out from within the template to properly define the `callAllFunctions` function.

I then tried to ignore the option for properly typedeffing the whole tr1::function and just split this into returnType and parameterType within the class itself, which kind of works, but only with a fixed number of parameter:

```
template<typename R = void, typename P1 = void>
class FunctionStore
{
        typedef tr1::function<R( P1 & )> Function;

    public:
        FunctionStore<R, P1>();
        virtual ~FunctionStore();

        void addFunction( const Function &newFunction )
        {
            functionStorage.push_back(newFunction);
        }

        void callAllFunctions( const P1 &parameter ) const
        {
            for( Function fn : functionStorage)
            {
                fn(parameter);
            }
        }

    private:
        vector<Function> functionStorage;
};
```

But with this, I can not really make the P1 Type optional. I tried this with defaulting it to void, but because i use it as `P1 & parameter`, it would evaluate to expecting a `fn(void &)`, which is not the same as `fn()`. Also, not using the `&` does not work because it creates an illegal void reference. I also thought about variadic parameters because it would kind of solve the optional requirement, but since the parameter number and types are obviously actually defined in the types (and needed for the tr1::bind placeholder stuff), this seems to be the wrong way to go.

So how can I make this happen. I assume there is no real way to make the first option (which I would obviously prefer) happen, so a solution to the second is still much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to C++11?  I presume not.

Comment: Well, kind of, as this should be run on Windows too, i compile against a minGW's GCC4.7 with C++0x.. So basically C++11, but some stuff like functions is still in tr1.. but for the sake of simplicity, assume c++11..

Answer (score 0):

With C++11 and variadic template, you may do:

```
template<typename R = void, typename... Args>
class FunctionStore
{
        typedef tr1::function<R(const Args&)> Function;

    public:
        FunctionStore<R, P1>();
        virtual ~FunctionStore();

        void addFunction( const Function &newFunction )
        {
            functionStorage.push_back(newFunction);
        }

        void callAllFunctions(const Args... &parameters) const
        {
            for( Function fn : functionStorage)
            {
                fn(parameters...);
            }
        }

    private:
        vector<Function> functionStorage;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Specialize:

```
template<class Sig>
class FunctionStore;

template<class R, class...Args>
class FunctionStore<R(Args...)> {
    typedef std::tr1::function<R( Args... )> Function;
  public:
    FunctionStore() {}
    virtual ~FunctionStore() {}

    void addFunction( Function f ) {
        functionStorage.emplace_back(std::move(f)); // or push_back on C++03
    }

    template<class...Ts>
    void callAllFunctions( Ts&&... ts) const
    {
      for( auto&& fn : functionStorage) {
        bool last_iteration = &fn == functionStorage.data()+functionStorage.size()-1;
        if (last_iteration)
          fn(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
        else
          fn(ts...); // or remove all the rest of the loop body, and just fn(ts...)
      }
    }
  private:
    std::vector<Function> functionStorage;
};
```

now, `last_iteration` is probably too much micro optimization.  Just `fn(args...)`.

Now, the above uses perfect forwarding instead of explicit arguments to `callAllFunctions`, and perfect forwarding is very slightly imperfect.  You could instead make the signature `callAllFunctions( Args... args )` with no `template` parameters, which would allow `{}` based construction and the like.

Comment: So, after learnong a lot about forward, lvalues and rvalues I was not aware of before, I got some questions: a) I assume it should be `data()*(size()-1)` in your last iteration check? b) I assume it should be `ts ...` in the last iteration else branch? c) you are doing the perfect forward only in the last iteration so multiple function calls don't use the same rvalues? (I'm not really sure about this?

Comment: Also, I'm not really sure I understood the concept of the inner template member functions, because since I ultimately store tr1::functions, F would need to be the same constructed type I already did with the Function typedef and since Ts could be different from Args, wouldn't that allow to call the stored functions with parameter which they were not designed for? Same in the addFunction() where I can't construct a tr1::function from an arbitrary object, can I?

Comment: @DragonTEC No, `data()` is a pointer, so should get added to.  `F` does not have to be `tr1::function` -- it needs be anything that can be used to CONSTRUCT a `tr1::function`, like a lambda or a function object or a function pointer or `std::nullptr`.  We could simply take a `tr1::function` and `std::move` from it now that I think about it.  I'll change that.  Next, you'll get a compile time error if you call a function with incorrect parameters, even if it happens in the body of a template method.  So it won't ever call it with the wrong arguments.